# How to store a Complex Nested JSON in Redis using Python

Tags: python, json, redis

As i am new to redis, i need some guidance on how we can store the below complex json in REDIS so that we can access the Elements of the JSON from REDIS -

```
"Reservations": [
        {
            "Instances": [
                {
                    "Monitoring": {
                        "State": "disabled"
                    },
                    "PublicDnsName": "",
                    "State": {
                        "Code": 16,
                        "Name": "running"
                    },
                    "EbsOptimized": "false",
                    "LaunchTime": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "PrivateIpAddress": "x.x.x.x",
                    "ProductCodes": [],
                    "VpcId": "xxxxx",
                    "StateTransitionReason": "",
                    "InstanceId": "i-xxxxxxx",
                    "EnaSupport": "true",
                    "ImageId": "ami-xxxxx",
                    "PrivateDnsName": "ip-xxxxxx.ec2.internal",
                    "KeyName": "xxxxxxv",
                    "SecurityGroups": [
                        {
                            "GroupName": "xxx",
                            "GroupId": "sg-xxxx"
                        },
                        {
                            "GroupName": "xxxxxx",
                            "GroupId": "sg-xxxxx"
                        },
                        {
                            "GroupName": "xxxxx",
                            "GroupId": "sg-xxxxxx"
                        },
                        {
                            "GroupName": "xxxxx",
                            "GroupId": "sg-xxxxxx"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ClientToken": "xxxxx",
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-xxxxx",
                    "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                    "NetworkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "Status": "in-use",
                            "MacAddress": "xxxxxxxx",
                            "SourceDestCheck": "true",
                            "VpcId": "vpc-xxxxx",
                            "Description": "",
                            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-xxxxx",
                            "PrivateIpAddresses": [
                                {
                                    "PrivateDnsName": "ip-xx-ec2.internal",
                                    "Primary": "true",
                                    "PrivateIpAddress": "xxxxx"
                                }
                            ],
                            "PrivateDnsName": "ip-xxxx-xx.ec2.internal",
                            "Attachment": {
                                "Status": "attached",
                                "DeviceIndex": 0,
                                "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
                                "AttachmentId": "eni-attach-xxxxx",
                                "AttachTime": "2017-0xxxxx"
                            },
                            "Groups": [
                                {
                                    "GroupName": "xx",
                                    "GroupId": "sg-xxxx"
                                },
                                {
                                    "GroupName": "xxxx",
                                    "GroupId": "sg-xxx"
                                },
                                {
                                    "GroupName": "xxxx",
                                    "GroupId": "sg-xxx"
                                },
                                {
                                    "GroupName": "xxxx",
                                    "GroupId": "sg-xxxx"
                                }
                            ],
                            "Ipv6Addresses": [],
                            "OwnerId": "xxx",
                            "SubnetId": "subnet-xxxx",
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "1xxxx"
                        }
                    ],
                    "SourceDestCheck": "true",
                    "Placement": {
                        "Tenancy": "default",
                        "GroupName": "",
                        "AvailabilityZone": "us-xxxxxxx"
                    },
                    "Hypervisor": "xen",
                    "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                        {
                            "DeviceName": "/dev/xxxxxx",
                            "Ebs": {
                                "Status": "attached",
                                "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
                                "VolumeId": "vol-xxxxxx",
                                "AttachTime": "2017-xxxxxxx"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "Architecture": "x86_64",
                    "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
                    "IamInstanceProfile": {
                        "Id": "xxxxxxxx",
                        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx"
                    },
                    "RootDeviceName": "/dev/xxxxx",
                    "VirtualizationType": "hvm",
                    "Tags": [
                        {
                            "Value": "xxxxxx",
                            "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-name"
                        },
                        {
                            "Value": "xxxxxxx",
                            "Key": "aws:cloudformation:logical-id"
                        },
                        {
                            "Value": "arn:aws:cloudformation:xxxxxx",
                            "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-id"
                        }
                    ],
                    "AmiLaunchIndex": 0
                }
            ],
            "ReservationId": "r-xxxxx",
            "RequesterId": "xxxxx",
            "Groups": [],
            "OwnerId": "xxxxxx"
        }
    ] 
}
```

I need to store this in such a way that i query the IP/Hostname/InstanceID to get all the elements that are present in the JSON.

I need some guidance on the above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't directly do that, but luckily there is a new Redis module called RedisJSON that does exactly what you need, and it has a nice Python binding as well. You can launch a [RedisJSON docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/redislabs/rejson/) or use Redis 4.0+, then [download](https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise-software/download-center/modules/)/compile and install RedisJSON and configure Redis to load it, and it adds native commands for JSON manipulation.

It lets you store JSON documents in Redis, and then either fetch or modify a specific element in the document tree, without retrieving (or internally even parsing) the document. Its Python client even lets you store python dicts and converts them to JSON automatically.

ReJSON module: http://redisjon.io

Python client: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rejson

Example:

```
from rejson import Client, Path

rj = Client(host='localhost', port=6379)

# Set the key `obj` to some object
obj = {
    'answer': 42,
    'arr': [None, True, 3.14],
    'truth': {
        'coord': 'out there'
    }
}
rj.jsonset('obj', Path.rootPath(), obj)

# Get something
print 'Is there anybody... {}?'.format(
    rj.jsonget('obj', Path('.truth.coord'))
)
```

Comment: Took the words out of my mouth :)

Comment: Works beautifully, i have a question though, if i want to print the Tags Elements of the JSON how do i do that, i tried the below, but it gives me an error - `print(r.jsonget('obj', Path('.Reservations.Instances.Tags')))`

Comment: @RohitSarkar it's unrelated to ReJSON, I think your path is wrong. From looking at the document I can see that it should be `.Reservations[0].Instances[0].Tags`

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer - Thanks that worked, sorry i am a bit of a noob with Python and Redis

Comment: it's more of a JSON thing, unrelated to both python and redis.

Comment: I guess i am noob there too. Thanks a lot for the guidance

Comment: As of redis-py 4.0.0 the rejson library is deprecated. It's features have been merged into redis-py.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **pickle** module incase you don't want to use reJson.

To set data in redis:

```
def store_dict_data_in_redis(redis_client, key, data, ex=0):
'''
store dict data in redis by pickle dumps
:param redis_client: redis client used to connect to obtain key value
:param key: key name
:param data: dict value
:param ex: expiry
:return: None
'''
    if ex > 0:
         redis_client.set(key, pickle.dumps(data), ex=ex)
    else:
         redis_client.set(key, pickle.dumps(data))
```

To obtain value from redis:

```
def get_dict_data_from_redis(redis_client, key):
'''
obtain dict data from redis
:param redis_client: redis client used to connect to obtain key value
:param key: key name
:return: dict data stored in redis
'''
    data = redis_client.get(key)
    if data:
       try:
          return pickle.loads(data)
       except:
          return eval(data.decode())
    return {}
```

Comment: You can't modify a pickled object inside redis, and if you load and serialize not only is it slow, but your data will be inconsistent really quickly.

Comment: The goal here was to store data in redis and not modify it along the fly. i knew tat you can use reJson to do so.Just gave an alternative :)

Comment: reJson also needs minimum redis requirement of 4.0 or above.
link : http://rejson.io/

Answer (score 1):

I used this method to save data in JSON format in Radis and it worked on my project properly, ‍‍‍‍

`Note` That I have defined an expiration time for data storage‍
‍‍‍‍

```py
import redis
import json

rs = redis.Redis(host="127.0.0.1", port=6379, decode_responses=True)

def set_json(data, expire_time):
   for key in data.keys():
       if rs.set(key, str(data[key]), expire_time) is False:
           return False
       return True

def get_json(topic):
    value = rs.mget(topic)
    if value is not None:
        return json.loads(json.dumps(value[0]))
    return False


data = {
        "topic": 
        {
            "key0":"value",
            "key1":
            [
                {"key3":1}
            ]
        }
    }

set_json(data, 50)

topic = get_json("topic")
print(topic)
```

Output :

```sh
>> {'key0': 'value', 'key1': [{'key3': 1}]}
```